# create custom function in jquery this function value can't get

Tags: jquery

i am create check_agent_session() return response check below code

```
function check_agent_session(){
      var response = ''
      $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>agent/agent_session",
          success: function(res){
               response = $.parseJSON(res);
               response = response['message'];


             }
         });
        // alert(response);
         return response;
     }

  });
```

after i will put this function page document read

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
alert(check_agent_session());
});
```

this function return value balnk. alert as blank.

Please guide me

Comment: debug and check what is returning from `$.parseJSON(res);`

Comment: AJAX - as its name implies - is asynchronous. Therefore you return `response` before it has been set. See the duplicate questions for an explanation of the issue and the solution

Comment: @UmairAnwaar reposnse i get value true or false; i will check that. it's working fine;